# How to get list of available devices connected with wifi

Tags: ios, ios4, wifi

I want to get list of available wifi devices in iphone.

how to do this?

Comment: Have you Managed to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have tried this link but no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303123/ios-how-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-wifi-network-given-the-ssid-and-passw/41998372