# iOS how to open phone Wifi hotspot through coding?

Tags: ios, wifi

I want open phone wifi hotspot in my app And get wifi's SSID Password, who can tell me how to realize it.

Comment: [Refer this so post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303123/ios-how-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-wifi-network-given-the-ssid-and-passw)

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: This can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed by Apple. But you can implement that for hacked iPhones.
App example: https://intelliborn.com/mywi.html