# How to scan all available wifi and connect with particular wifi

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to get wifi's SSID and password from server and I have to check any available wifi's SSID is matched with my server's SSID. If any matched, I have to connect with that wifi using its password. I have read many post related to this but I couldn't get any answer.

Comment: Sorry. I haven't tried with any codes, even i don't have an idea how to achieve.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask] and [mcve]. And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in iOS. The only thing you can retrieve is the SSID **after** the user has connected to one of the Wi-Fi networks **using the regular iOS UI**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hotspot Configuration to register SSID/password to connect to.

For more info, see [iOS - How to programmatically connect to a WiFi network given the SSID and Password using a private/3rd party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303123/ios-how-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-wifi-network-given-the-ssid-and-passw)