# how to connect to specific wifi in xamarin ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to connect to wifi....................................................................
Here is my code:

```
NEHotspotConfigurationManager wifiManager = new NEHotspotConfigurationManager();
var wifiConfig = new NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid, password, false) { JoinOnce = true };
wifiManager.RemoveConfiguration(ssid);
wifiManager.ApplyConfigurationAsync(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.ApplyConfiguration(wifiConfig, (error) =>
{
if (error != null)
{
Console.WriteLine($"Error while connecting to WiFi network {ssid}: {error.Description}");
}
});
return true;
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673931/8187800

Answer (score 1):

Just like @cole-xia-msft mentioned the link for the configuration [work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/47673931/8187800), the C# code would look like this.

```
var configuration = new NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfiguration("SSID", "Password", false);
configuration.JoinOnce = true;

NetworkExtension.NEHotspotConfigurationManager.SharedManager.ApplyConfiguration(configuration, (NSError error) => 
{
    if (error != null) {
        if (error?.LocalizedDescription == "already associated.")
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No Connected");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
});
```

If your function enclosing the `ApplyConfiguration` call is asynchronous, you should consider using `ApplyConfigurationAsync` instead

Comment: Error Domain=NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=8 "internal error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=internal error.}

Comment: When you place an exception catchpoint, what line does it their the exception

Comment: In "ApplyConfiguration" line.

Comment: @Kefi Did you ever resolve this issue? I have enabled the hot spot entitlement, but no luck :-(