# Getting Wifi(SSID) List ios Application and connect with my application is that possible?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created one application getting all the wifi *(SSID)* near in my device is that possible, any library or third party getting wifi *(SSID)* list and connect in my application.

Can anyone help me out?

```
func getAllWiFiNameList() -> String? {
            var ssid: String?
            if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray? {
            for interface in interfaces {
            if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                        ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            return ssid
        }
```

Comment: A search for "ios list of wifi" or so shows a whole number of identical questions. The "Related" section on the right side of the question also lists a number of these.

Comment: yes @Roope my question i am getting list of wifi near my device and connect with my app is it possible in ios?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS - How to programmatically connect to a WiFi network given the SSID and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303123/ios-how-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-wifi-network-given-the-ssid-and-passw)