# How to measure WiFi Signal strength in iOS

Tags: swift, objective-c

I want to measure WIFI signal strength in iOS. Below would be the expectation

1. Scan and get List of Wifi
2. Connect to WiFi and measure WIFI signal strength in dBm.

Can anyone help how to do this in iOS as there are some restrictions in iOS APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do # 1 via [`NEHotspotHelper`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/hotspot_helper).

Here's [a thread where you can find more information](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/nehotspothelper-swift-code-for-gathering-available-ssids/37702), plus a [sample github repo](https://github.com/EyreFree/EFNEHotspotHelperDemo)!

You can do # 2 via [NetworkExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration)

More information in [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303123/ios-how-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-wifi-network-given-the-ssid-and-passw)

Both of these require a special entitlement you need to apply for.  Check out the paragraph [at the start of the `NEHotspotHelper` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/hotspot_helper).

Comment: Thank you Michael, I will try to explore both ways.