# How to decode a QR code that contains data for WIFI connection in AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I use AVFoundation to read the QR Code, after reading I get a string, the pattern "WIFI:S:name-of-network;T:WPA;P:password;;"
How do I decode, with the ability to connect, and output separately password, name in label.text

I am new to swift, I would be grateful if you could describe the solution to the problem in detail. Thank you.

Comment: https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-split-string-into-array-of-substrings-in-swift/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303123/how-to-programmatically-connect-to-a-wifi-network-given-the-ssid-and-password